# Is it possible to include HTMLElements block inside another HTMLElements block

Tags: htmlelements

Could someone please clarify whether it is possible to include HTMLElements block inside another HTMLElements block.

Comment: Why do we need html tag inside other html tag ? Can you please tell us your requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, why not? Actually using blocks inside blocks is the main reason to use htmlelements at all.